# protect vs safeguard

Tags: difference

I'd like to compare "protect" and "safeguard". For this purpose I prepared some examples.

(1a) & (2a) are from [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/protect):
**(1a)** *Sunscreen helps to **protect against** sunburn*.
**(2a)** *The insurance does not **protect against** damage caused by earthquakes*.
my variants with "from":
**(3a)** *Sunscreen helps to **protect from** sunburn*.
**(4a)** *The insurance does not **protect from** damage caused by earthquakes*.

my variants with "safeguard":
**(1b)** *Sunscreen helps to **safeguard against** sunburn*.
**(2b)** *The insurance does not **safeguard against** damage caused by earthquakes*.
**(3b)** *Sunscreen helps to **safeguard from** sunburn*.
**(4b)** *The insurance does not **safeguard from** damage caused by earthquakes*.

Could you tell me please which of my variants [(3a), (4a), (1b), (2b), (3b), (4b)] are correct and which are not?

Comment: 3a, 4a, 3b and 4b sound a bit odd without an object. E.g. "Sunscreen helps to protect **the skin** from sunburn." — "The insurance does not protect **customers** from damage caused by earthquakes." —